# How to call FragmentStatePagerAdapter from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have 2 fragments- list fragment and detail fragment. When I click on the item of list fragment, is should redirect me to the detail fragment. In detail page I should use view pager. It worked using pager adapter. But I should use fragment state pager adapter. How to call the this adapter from fragment. I tried using it...but it will return an empty container.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.. Thanks in Adavance...

Comment: what kind of data do you want to pass to the adapter?

Comment: I got it.. I need to create one more fragment and in that fragment i should set the layout for the view pager.Now its working properly